# FF 3 Factor Data for Europe

Tags: factor-models

Since FF library is for US. How can I get the SMB and HML fators for European markets (UK, France, Germany, etc)?

Comment: It is not true that Kenneth French's web site only covers the US http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/int_index_port_formed.html

Answer (score 2):

You can get a pooled European market at Kenneth French's website, you just have to scroll down. These are current.

German factors are here, but I think they might have stopped updating them in 2016: 
https://www.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/de/professuren/bwl/bb/data/fama-french-factors-germany/fama-french-factors-for-germany

Stefano Marni has a large set of monthly factors, including France, however, they stop in 2013.

http://homepage.sns.it/marmi/Data_Library.html

Similarly, Tharayan and Christidis offer daily UK factors, they stop in June 2015.

http://business-school.exeter.ac.uk/research/centres/xfi/famafrench/

Comment: Some big European investment bank should pay Humboldt, or Monsieur Marni or Tharayan to update these factors every month...